# Docusign API template ID

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the following steps to successfully create our app while in testing mode but we cannot go live because the template ID is not there for a standard account.

1. We create the template at demo.docusign.net
2. We get the template ID
3. Our app works perfectly using API

But a normal user (our client) will create a template using docusign.com ... which does not Display the template ID and therefore he cannot put it in the APP.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.  When editing a template, the first page (which shows all of the details of the template) displays the Template ID at the top left.  They could copy and paste it.

Arguably the better user experience is to use the DocuSign API to get a list of the available template names/IDs and let your users select the appropriate template within your app.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client sample and testing please make sure you create a sandbox environment on docusign as the above sample uses https://demo.docusign.net/restapi as the Api URL,create integrator key and create template in demo environment only.I experienced same error(invalid template id) when I created a template on real(not sandbox) environment and used the above sample having demo API URL in my application and later when I changed to demo template id( by clicking cursor on (i)) I got the desired result.

Thanks
Ravi